# structuring JSON data in R

Tags: r, json, dataframe, data-cleaning

I'm new to JSON data and am having a bit of trouble trying to get my data into a combined data frame common to data frames in R. Here is an example of the JSON data:

```
{
  "id": "rub_al_khali",
  "conversion_px": 0.0395882818685669,
  "n_surfaces": 4,
  "lithic_contours": [
    {
      "surface_id": 0,
      "classification": "Ventral",
      "total_area_px": 530565.5,
      "total_area": 831.5,
      "max_breadth": 22.4,
      "max_length": 54,
      "polygon_count": 7,
      "scar_count": 0,
      "percentage_detected_scars": 0,
      "scar_contours": []
    },
    {
      "surface_id": 1,
      "classification": "Dorsal",
      "total_area_px": 530503.5,
      "total_area": 831.4,
      "max_breadth": 22.4,
      "max_length": 54,
      "polygon_count": 7,
      "scar_count": 4,
      "percentage_detected_scars": 0.62,
      "scar_contours": [
        {
          "scar_id": 0,
          "total_area_px": 129337,
          "total_area": 202.7,
          "max_breadth": 10.3,
          "max_length": 41.7,
          "percentage_of_surface": 0.24,
          "scar_angle": 1.85,
          "polygon_count": 5
        },
        {
          "scar_id": 1,
          "total_area_px": 100130,
          "total_area": 156.9,
          "max_breadth": 7.2,
          "max_length": 43,
          "percentage_of_surface": 0.19,
          "scar_angle": 357.36,
          "polygon_count": 4
        },
        {
          "scar_id": 2,
          "total_area_px": 93162,
          "total_area": 146,
          "max_breadth": 6.5,
          "max_length": 41.4,
          "percentage_of_surface": 0.18,
          "scar_angle": 5.01,
          "polygon_count": 4
        },
        {
          "scar_id": 3,
          "total_area_px": 6148.5,
          "total_area": 9.6,
          "max_breadth": 4,
          "max_length": 7.1,
          "percentage_of_surface": 0.01,
          "scar_angle": "NaN",
          "polygon_count": 9
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "surface_id": 2,
      "classification": "Lateral",
      "total_area_px": 176204,
      "total_area": 276.2,
      "max_breadth": 8.6,
      "max_length": 54.2,
      "polygon_count": 3,
      "scar_count": 2,
      "percentage_detected_scars": 0.33,
      "scar_contours": [
        {
          "scar_id": 0,
          "total_area_px": 44605,
          "total_area": 69.9,
          "max_breadth": 5,
          "max_length": 50,
          "percentage_of_surface": 0.25,
          "scar_angle": "NaN",
          "polygon_count": 3
        },
        {
          "scar_id": 1,
          "total_area_px": 12877,
          "total_area": 20.2,
          "max_breadth": 1.5,
          "max_length": 22.3,
          "percentage_of_surface": 0.07,
          "scar_angle": "NaN",
          "polygon_count": 2
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "surface_id": 3,
      "classification": "Platform",
      "total_area_px": 55252.5,
      "total_area": 86.6,
      "max_breadth": 20.3,
      "max_length": 6.6,
      "polygon_count": 5,
      "scar_count": 1,
      "percentage_detected_scars": 0.42,
      "scar_contours": [
        {
          "scar_id": 0,
          "total_area_px": 23298.5,
          "total_area": 36.5,
          "max_breadth": 15,
          "max_length": 4.1,
          "percentage_of_surface": 0.42,
          "scar_angle": "NaN",
          "polygon_count": 4
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

So far I've used jsonlite to import to R using flatten = TRUE

```
library(jsonlite)
dta <- fromJSON("~/rub_al_khali.json", flatten = TRUE)
```

and while this gets me half way there it's not really a combined/comprehensive `data.frame`. I think that it might be the dta$lithic_contours that is creating the issue. Any help is much appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`jsonlite::fromJSON()` returns a list, but the element `lithic_contours` contains a data.frame. Just subset the list to get your data.frame:

```r
# Subset the list on lithic_contours with $ ...
df <- jsonlite::fromJSON(<file>, flatten = TRUE)$lithic_contours

# ... and it's already a data.frame
class(df)
#> [1] "data.frame"

# Turning into a tibble for better printing
tibble::as_tibble(df)
#> # A tibble: 4 × 10
#>   surface_id classification total_area_px total_area max_breadth max_length
#>        <int> <chr>                  <dbl>      <dbl>       <dbl>      <dbl>
#> 1          0 Ventral              530566.      832.         22.4       54  
#> 2          1 Dorsal               530504.      831.         22.4       54  
#> 3          2 Lateral              176204       276.          8.6       54.2
#> 4          3 Platform              55252.       86.6        20.3        6.6
#> # … with 4 more variables: polygon_count <int>, scar_count <int>,
#> #   percentage_detected_scars <dbl>, scar_contours <list>
```

<sup>Created on 2022-04-04 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

#### Update: unnesting list column

The `scar_contours` column of your dataframe is a list column. This is actually often a quite convenient format for analysis, but if you want to remove it you can use the function `tidyr::unnest()`:

```r
library(tidyr)

df %>% unnest(scar_contours, names_repair = "minimal")
#> # A tibble: 7 × 17
#>   surface_id classification total_area_px total_area max_breadth max_length
#>        <int> <chr>                  <dbl>      <dbl>       <dbl>      <dbl>
#> 1          1 Dorsal               530504.      831.         22.4       54  
#> 2          1 Dorsal               530504.      831.         22.4       54  
#> 3          1 Dorsal               530504.      831.         22.4       54  
#> 4          1 Dorsal               530504.      831.         22.4       54  
#> 5          2 Lateral              176204       276.          8.6       54.2
#> 6          2 Lateral              176204       276.          8.6       54.2
#> 7          3 Platform              55252.       86.6        20.3        6.6
#> # … with 11 more variables: polygon_count <int>, scar_count <int>,
#> #   percentage_detected_scars <dbl>, scar_id <int>, total_area_px <dbl>,
#> #   total_area <dbl>, max_breadth <dbl>, max_length <dbl>,
#> #   percentage_of_surface <dbl>, scar_angle <dbl>, polygon_count <int>
```

Comment: @ jpiversen So, I've done this, there are still more data frames nested. For example - df[[10]][[2]]. Is there a way to get it all in one viewable data frame for analysis?

Comment: @ jpiversen Thanks for the update. Why is the current structure a convenient format for analysis?

Comment: It's often convenient as an intermediate structure. You can keep data together with metadata, which I assume is what you have here. It's most useful if you already know `purrr` and functional programming. I often use this structure to create models or plots for many datasets at the same time. You can see some examples [here](https://r4ds.had.co.nz/many-models.html).

Comment: Thanks for this. I'm new to working with this type of data. I'll be checking out the examples. Right now I'm gong through the data in R and am starting to get a feel for it.

Comment: You're welcome. By the way, if my answer above solved your problem, please consider "accepting" by clicking the check mark under the arrows. See [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) for what it means to accept an answer.